# How to implement fusion layer technique in pytorch?

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch, data-science

Currently, I'm working on creating image colorization model. I want to use in it fusion layer, [presented](http://iizuka.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/projects/colorization/en/) by Iizuki et al., but I have some problem with implementing it in Pytorch.

The basic idea is that we extract mid-level features and global features from image independtly, then combine them according to [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M6IU.png)
where u,v is number of "pixel", y_global - global feature vector of size 64, y^mid_u_v - mid-level feature vector of size 64. So we concat

Output shape  of my midlevel layer is (bs, 64, 28, 28), output shape of my global feature extractor is (bs, 64).

I tried to calculate per-pixel, using nn.Embedding(), but it seems to work incorrectly, assuming bs is not 1.

How to implement this technique elegantly and effectively in Pytorch?

I tried to calculate per-pixel, using nn.Embedding(), but it seems to work bad

Comment: bs is for batch_size